# Apple's Notes forgetting notes -- why?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, notes.app

I started to use the default Notes app over iPhone, iPad and Macbook. After it sends me an email about the note, the note gets removed. I want to keep the notes. My friend suspected a time-drift bug in Apple but I checked and the devices are in the same time. It is very hard to believe this is an intentional feature. I use sync over iCloud. I have OS X 10.7.5, iPhone 4S and iPad 2.

**How can I get notes unremoved?**

Comment: What the app forgets for me is its window position and whether the folder pane is open or closed. OS X 10.8.2.

Comment: How are you using Notes.app on OS X 10.7?

Comment: Ah, right. No, there's no standalone Notes.app for 10.7, you can only use it through Mail.app.

Comment: Could you edit and tag this if you are syncing notes as part of a third party email service or over iCloud? Both are possible so it's likely this is part of the issue.